# Make uib-typeahead behave like a select or format a select like uib-typehead?

Tags: select, angular-ui-bootstrap, typeahead

is it possible to make a uib-typeahead behave like a dropdown select ?

I like the style of uib-typeahead when you use typeahead-min-length="0", and when you just click the text input you get all the possible options, so this kind of does what I want...

However, once you selected a first option, and you want to try another one, to get back the full list of options, you need to remove all the text from the input field first... whereas I would like to get it just by clicking the field.

So I would like to always get the full options list whatever text is already input... I know this is a bit against the idea of 'typeahead' if the tool doesn't care what you 'type ahead' ;)...

Another option would be to try and style a select with ng-options to look the same as uib-typeahead but I've read that it was not possible because the select dropdown list was a browser buitlin component. (is that correct?)

Any idea? Many thanks!